# How can I add request header parameters in HTTP integration WebSocket api gateway AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudshell

I'm new to AWS. I want to add header parameters to my HTTP request. I tried the below command in CloudShell but it was not working.

`aws apigatewayv2 update-integration --integration-id xxx --api-id xxxxx --request-parameters 'integration.request.header.Some-Header-Param'= 'SomeText'`

It is giving the below error:

`An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the UpdateIntegration operation: Invalid mapping expression specified: Validation Result: warnings : [], errors : [Invalid mapping expression specified: SomeText]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Searching for while I found the Answer from https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/api-gateway-vpc-link-integration

1. To retrieve the integration ID, run the AWS CLI command get-integrations similar to the following:

> `aws apigatewayv2 get-integrations --api-id <api-id>`

2. Create and save a JSON file named integration.json in the following format:

> ````
> {
>     "ApiId": "<api-id>",
>     "IntegrationId": "<integration id retrieved from previous step>",
>     "RequestParameters": {
>         "integration.request.header.ConnectionId": "context.connectionId", //passing context variable connectionId as ConnectionId header to backend
>         "integration.request.header.any-header-key": "''static value'",   //passing static value as querystring to backend
>         "integration.request.querystring.any-querystring-key": "'static value'"
>     } 
> } ```
> ````

3. To update the integration, run the AWS CLI command update-integration similar to the following:

> `aws apigatewayv2 update-integration --cli-input-json file://integration.json`

4. Deploy your API